# How to setup TL-WR1043ND router on 12.04

Tags: router

I've recently acquired the above router and want to give it a go.

Problem is, when ?I go to the TP-Link website to download the 'Easy setup' software there's no version available for linux.

anyone know how I can set the router up without the 'Easy setup' software - please bear in mind that I'm a linux noob and know virtually nothing about routers and/or networking!

Comment: This should perhaps be a better fit with our fellow Stackexchange friends - SuperUser.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually routers are set up by accessing a web interface by entering their ip address in a web browser while being connected to the router. In the case of your router the default IP address is 192.168.1.1.

The default username and password is "admin" for both.

Once you're in the admin panel you can change all the settings as you wish.

Comment: Agree. The strict instructions of TP-Link with their products to use the software on the CD should not be followed in my opinion. Just use the web interface that works out of the box.