# How do I prioritize internet traffic in my local network for individual PCs?

Tags: internet-connection

Got three pcs (two linux, one windows) on my wireless home network. Is there any way to 'prioritise' internet usage/traffic for these machines e.g.

Make pc 1 always have higher priority on internet usage than pc #3?

Comment: Did you try adding the different MAC addresses for the device and assigning them priority?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, but don't try to do this in Ubuntu or even on your PCs.

The machines in your network are autonomous and work independently. Traffic of these come together at your router/modem and *that's* where you can prioritize traffic. This is called QoS (Quality of Service) and most routers let you prioritize traffic based on several properties: source IP address, port number, etc. Reading your [other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/218850/88802) I think you have a device quite capable of doing this.

Please re-ask your question on [Superuser.com](http://superuser.com) where this is more on topic. (or moderator may have it migrated for you)